# geopandas loop does not give me name of layers

Tags: geopandas

I m trying to get a dataframe with all different layers of a kml. The code below gives a dataframe, but I also want the name of the kml layers to create a column in data. Any idea about what I m doing wrong?

```
gpd.io.file.fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['KML'] = 'rw'
fp="file.kml"
data = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
layers_list=pd.Series(fiona.listlayers(fp))
list(layers_list)

for l in layers_list :
        s = gpd.read_file(fp, driver='KML', layer=l)
        data = data.append(s, ignore_index=True)
        data['layers']= l
```

Comment: You need to add that "layers" column before appending: `s["layers"] = l`

Comment: oh ! Of course ! Thanks so much !